# Drawing a plot and calculating area in matlab

Tags: matlab

I need to draw the curve of x^3+y^3-3*a*x*y=0 and calculate its area. I'm new to matlab so I don't know much. Any help would be appreciated.
Here's what I came up with already`

```
function makeres(a)
syms x y;
k=y.^3+x.^3-3.*x.*a.*y==0;
ezplot(k)
fun=@(x)(k);
integral(integral(k,0,5),0,5)
```

But I get an error on integral.

Comment: To get the most out of the site it is important to ask good questions. A guide to asking questions is at: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  To that vein, what error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
syms x y;
k=y.^3+x.^3-3.*x.*a.*y==0;
ezplot(k)
fun=@(x,y)y.^3+x.^3-3.*x.*a.*y;
g = integral2(fun,0,5,0,5);
```

Your erros where in the last 2 lines:

a - you were defining k (which is an equation) as the function to be integrated

b - then you integrated k, not fun

c - it is better use integral2 for double integral

I'm don't know what `a` should be, it works for me when `a` is a number, an the code as a single script (not a defined function).